# What is an open surface bounded by a closed contour

Tags: surfaces

Can someone tell me what an open surface bounded by a closed contour is please? I have difficulties to imagine something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How bout $D^o = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\| < 1\}$?  This is an open set, and the closed contour bounding it is precisely $S^1 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\| = 1\}$.

Comment: oh that is meant with that. Thank you!